# cURL não funciona em determinado servidor

Tags: php

Estou co a seguinte situação: tem um código faz um post para uma API remota enviando um arquivo (imagem).

Funciona no servidor local (*localhost | Wampserver | PHP Version 5.5.12*)

Funciona no servidor da Digital Ocean (*Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler | PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24*)

Na Locaweb não funciona (*Server API: CGI/FastCGI | PHP Version 5.5.31*)

Já fiz diversas verificações e não encontrei nenhuma solução. Alguma sugestão de qual diretiva, versão, path, etc, do que verificar?

Comment: o CURL está realmente instalado no servidor?

Comment: Não funciona como? Dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, está instalado. Envia normalmente a parte de texto.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não envia a imagem para a API. O restante do formulário (só texto) envia normalmente.

Comment: https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Utilizando_cURL_quando_a_diretiva_allow_url_fopen_est%C3%A1_desativada

Comment: @Otto já verifiquei isso, alterei o que indica no artigo e não resolveu.

Comment: Pode ser o limite máximo de tamanho para upload ou post nesse servidor específico.

Comment: @bfavaretto também já verifiquei e está bem abaixo deste limite.

Comment: Você está usando o `curl_file_create` ou diretamente o `@arquivo` no POST? Se for o segundo método, que já é obsoleto, você tem que desabilitar o `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`.